# Apache+Phusion Passenger+Ruby on Rails synchronization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, synchronization, passenger

I am running Apache, Phusion Passenger, Ruby on Rails website. I have a critical section that I can only allow 1 execution at the same time. I noticed that phusion passenger uses fork() to spawn the processes for each request according to this [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_the_most_straightforward_and_traditional_way_direct_spawning). Since they are individual process, I noticed that all my Mutex.synchronize do not work. I added some loggings inside the critical section, and I still noticed logs being printed interleaving.

I tried all these:

1. Mutex.synchronize
2. Thread.exclusive
3. Monitor.synchronize

None of them works.

How do you do synchronization in this case? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Mutex, Monitor and Thread.exclusive only work within a single process. For inter-process synchronization, use lock files. See File#flock.